# Añadir lineas de un dataframe a otro cuando coinciden sobre valores de una columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo [un primer dataframe](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15OU7SwaxqW4vds3E2uN-exPiXOQg2bMJmrGcxIYalaI/edit?usp=sharing) al que debo añadir las líneas de [un segundo dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D-WhqHn4mPPSXbBDdk-cB7bdllLcK8W-/view?usp=sharing).

Este mas o menos como esta del primero:

```
    QID    Questions    B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F G H I J
0   3   a   4.0 a   a   a   a   e   g   i   l    
1   4   b   5.0 b   b   b   a   r   h   m   p
2   5   d   5.0 NaN e   d   b   u   e   i   z
3   6   e   5.0 d   h   r   b   c   z   i   3
...
```

Y el segundo:

```
    QID    Questions    B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F ...
0   1   a   4.0 a   a   a   a   
1   2   b   5.0 b   k   b   a   
2   2_1 z   5.0 b   k   b   a   
3   2_2 w   4.0 b   k   b   c   
4   3   d   5.0 NaN e   d   b   
5   4   e   5.0 d   h   r   b   
...
```

Me gustaría conseguir:

```
    QID    Questions    B   Answer1 Answer2 Answer3 F G H I J
0   3   a   4.0 a   a   a   a   e   g   i   l    
1   4   b   5.0 b   b   b   a   r   h   m   p
2   4_1 z   5.0 b   k   b   a   r   h   m   p
3   4_2 w   4.0 b   k   b   c   r   h   m   p
4   5   d   5.0 NaN e   d   b   u   e   i   z
5   6   e   5.0 d   h   r   b   c   z   i   3
...
```

Como pueden ver los dataframes comparten la Questions `b` así que he añadido las siguientes líneas que incluyen `_` en el nuevo dataframe.

Literalmente esto significa que el primer cuadro de datos y el segundo cuadro de datos comparten los mismos textos `t1` y `t2` en las celdas de la columna "Respuestas". Pero para una combinación dada (t1,t2) donde `t1 == t2`, cuando también hay filas debajo de ella de tal manera que QID tiene un `_` entonces quiero añadir esas filas después de la fila en la que se registraron.

Hasta hoy intenté:

```
rows_to_add = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row1 in df.iterrows():
  for j, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    if row1['Questions'] == row2['Questions']:
      # here I want to test if the next row has _ in his QID
      # if so I add all the lines with the same QID before _ but with row1 QID
      k = 0
      for _, next_row_df2 in df2[j+1:].iterrows():
        if "_" in str(next_row_df2['QID']):
          next_row_df2['QID'] = str(row1['QID']) + '_' + k
          rows_to_add += next_row_df2 # but I need to change the QID
        else:
          break # exit this loop and add the lines to the dataframe
        k += 1
      df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:i], rows_to_add, df.iloc[i:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
      rows_to_add = pd.DataFrame()
```

Pero no añade las filas. Tal vez podría hacerlo de una manera más eficiente: iterar sólo en las líneas df2 donde hay `_`? O con mapa-reduce?

Tal vez podría hacerlo de una manera más eficiente: iterar sólo en las líneas df2 donde hay _ ? Utilisar map reduce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aunque la explicación que das está un poco confusa, creo que entiendo lo que pides, corrigeme si hay alguna confusión.

1. De las preguntas que hay en el **dataframe_1** encontrar si la pregunta está repetida en el **dataframe_2**
2. Si la pregunta está repetida, buscar las subpreguntas en el **dataframe_2** que tienen un guión bajo en el **QID**.
3. Reemplazar el **QID** de las subpreguntas en **dataframe 2**, por el **QID** de la pregunta en **dataframe 1**.

Podemos crear un método para que haga estas funciones:

```
# leemos los datos
df1 = pd.read_csv('dataframe_1.csv', index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('dataframe_2.csv', index_col=0)

# limpio las preguntas y qid que están vacios
df1 = df1.dropna(subset=['Questions', 'QID'])
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['Questions', 'QID'])

def question_checker(qid, question, df2):
    """
    Input:
        qid: id de la pregunta en df1
        question: texto de la pregunta en df1
        df2: dataframe donde buscaremos si hay preguntas repetidas y las subpreguntas 
    Output:
        subquestions_df: dataframe with all subquestions found in df2
    """

    # buscamos si la pregunta está en el dataframe 2
    repeated_question = df2[df2['Questions'] == question]
    
    # si existe, buscamos por el qid de la pregunta en el dataframe 2
    if len(repeated_question) > 0:
        for i, row in repeated_question.iterrows():
            df2_qid = row['QID']
            sub_questions = df2[df2['QID'].str.startswith(f'{df2_qid}_')]

            # si hay subpreguntas, reemplazamos el qid
            if len(sub_questions) > 0:
                sub_questions['QID'] = sub_questions['QID'].str.replace(df2_qid, qid)
                return sub_questions
```

Y por último, utilizamos este método para revisar todas las preguntas en el **dataframe_1**

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    qid = row['QID']
    question = row['Questions']
    sub_rows = question_checker(qid, question, df2)
    if sub_rows is not None:
        new_df = new_df.append(sub_rows)
```

Y puedes unir este nuevo dataframe con el **dataframe_1**, poner el index, ordenarlo y demás.

Espero te sirva.